# Using a HashMap and an ArrayList to store variable names and values. How to use for creating new objects?

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I have a HashMap that stores the name of a object variable and the values that need to be used by the object.

The object creation will be:

```
Room [key] = new Room([value1]);
```

Below is the HashMap:

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> makeRoom(String[] room){
    map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        int roomNumber = Integer.parseInt(room[1]);

        List<String> valSetOne = new ArrayList<String>();
        valSetOne.add(room[2]);
        valSetOne.add(room[3]);
        valSetOne.add(room[4]);
        valSetOne.add(room[5]);

        map.put("r"+roomNumber, valSetOne);

        return map;
    }
}
```

How do I use this to produce a new object? For example, say I have 3 keys: `r1, r2, r3`. How can I produce the code:

```
Room r1 = new Room(1);
Room r2 = new Room(2);
Room r3 = new Room(3);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Can't you just use the map and associate a `String` key like `r1` with an instance? Then you can simply look up the instance based on the key. Code generation requires some specific circumstances, and there might be an easier solution to your problem.

Comment: Looks like Code Generation right?  Java is a compiled-time language. There are ways, but Java is not intended for it.

Comment: sounds like he wants a  key/value pair to have the key be the variable name and the value be the variable passed to the objects constructor.

Comment: I would make a dictionary/arraylist/hashmap of <String, Room> and add to it <key, new Room(value)>

Comment: @hardtacos what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @gtgaxiola yes, this is what I am attempting to do. Is it possible?

Comment: @HardTacos just use a `hashmap` `HashMap<String, Room>`    `key/room object`

Comment: @HardTacos `HashMap.put("r1", new Room(1));` This is like `Room r1 = new Room(1);`

Comment: @HardTacos Just create a `Map<String, Room>`, and map a string key to the appropriate room instance. There is no need to use reflection here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you can do something like this:

```
Constructor roomConstructor = Room.class.getConstructor(Integer.class);
Room r1 = roomConstructor.newInstance(Integer.parseInt(map.get("r1")));
Room r2 = roomConstructor.newInstance(Integer.parseInt(map.get("r2")));
Room r3 = roomConstructor.newInstance(Integer.parseInt(map.get("r3")));
```

The class object lets you grab a constructor and then create a new instance out of it, provided you pass in the correct parameters.